# Binding Two Property To ==> single Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, multibinding

Suppose I have property

`FIrstName` and `LastName`

I need to bound it with single `textbox`.

So in just **single textbox** I can display **both** `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Then how could it be possible?

Comment: Why not two textboxes, as is de facto standard on web forms?

Comment: seeing how you looked at the answers already, may I kindly re-ask 'Why not two textboxes, as is de facto standard on web forms?'; because I really doubt your application will be safe to use in case of bidirectional bindings; multi names are very common

Comment: we really need an "unhelpful-questioner" tag ...

Comment: @Pritesh: ping ping are you alive?

Comment: @Pritesh: *sigh* you are an unhelpful questioner, and tags are a central concept here on stackoverflow. You are unhelpful, because I've asked several times a question, each time you just ignored it. If you want us to help you, you have to help us first.

Comment: @phresnel, sorry for not replying or ignoring you but.....i think its not proper way to use two text-boxes...because if i need to display...city+PIN number(in india PIN= Postal Index Number as ZIP code in US). it is comman scenario to display PIN after city...than why not i using single TEXTBOX other than Two one....and WPF provide us best way for that and that is MULTI BINDING.  THANKS..........

Comment: @Pritesh: uhm, but you were talking FirstNames and LastNames, not Cities and PINs. Anyways, it is even common for Cities/PINs to be put in two textboxes. You should really look at other well-known websites how they compose their forms. Having two textboxes also gives you a programming advantage to supply some autocomplete function on either PIN or City; it is more difficult if they are thrown together.

Comment: @Pritesh: Also, of course it is your choice to accept an answer, as long as you do ;)

Comment: @phresnel, i am agree with you and your point is exactly right..and i will follow it....but my purpose here is to just display the string on form....i don't need input from user...as because i just want to print the displayed value....so ONE TEXTBOX  best suit for my scenario.

Comment: @Pritesh: Okay, but this is exactly what several ppl asked you, whether it is one-way or two-way. For just displaying, one box is fine. See, it is important to also help us, so we can better help you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multibinding  to do that

For **OnWay** Binding use this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
            <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

For more information about MutiBinding Class look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

Comment: out of curiosity: How will this handle `Karl Heinz Schmidt-Meyer von Neuenhausen zu Bad-Reichenhall`?

Comment: That is, a property value that starts with a “{“ (as the first character) is interpreted to be a markup extension, such as {Binding}, {DynamicResource}, {x:Null}, etc.  The way to really have a “{“ as the first character of a property value is to escape it with a “{}”. [look here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/29/trying-out-binding-stringformat.aspx)

Comment: for names like **Karl Heinz Schmidt-Meyer von Neuenhausen zu Bad-Reichenhall** you can use a separator like **,** between names

Comment: This code is for FirstName + " " + LastName and this code is better for showing data

Answer (score 2):

A third property `FullName`, perhaps.

For better help, please ask a better question (what are your types, e.g.).

edit: Anyways, I'd recommend to have at least two textboxes, so you can safely handle "multipart names", like the above mentioned `Karl Heinz Schmidt-Meyer von Neuenhausen zu Bad-Reichenhall`. Apart from being less ambiguous, this is a defacto standard on web-forms.

---

edit2: As a note about [Navid Rahmani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342773/binding-two-property-to-single-control/6342807#6342807) answer, because it opens up the potential for really severe database corruption, costs overtime for sys-admins, the programmers, who'll have no starting point and clue for why their application fails, and tons of money. That is, if this creepy corruption is ever discovered before your client has already lost its clients.

Code in question

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    string[] strings = ((string)value).Split(' ');
    return strings;
}
```

My question was how it would handle multipart names. He answered one could use "," then. My reply:

> Your code does not handle this, as it does not handle the case with less than two name components (you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`). Additionally, your code does not handle multiple or forgotten whitespaces. For each additional whitespace, it produces a seperate value-token, potentially **ruining database entries** with dissapearing data (because you only read the first two entries). Further, you must validate **if** the user did not forget the comma or mistyped e.g. with a semicolon or slash. All these problems cease to exist with seperation into distinct fields. User input is the number one security and program stability dread.

Comment: If you look at the title of the question **(Binding Two Property To ==> single Control)** What I wrote is a conceptual text, Actually I'm agree with you but this is not an end user code it's conceptual.

Comment: @Navid Rahmani: Still dangerous. Strangers will dig it up, take it for correct. In effect, not increasing our guilds fame.

Comment: take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [MultiBinding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) :

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
      <Binding Path="FirstName" />
      <Binding Path="LastName" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: dude, i missed out on the code sample button so it was not displayed... edited it as soon as i could, within a minute... ok, no problem...

Comment: Just curious, because I often see this happen here, putting those in disadvantage who write a complete post instead of just a very incomplete draft (sidenote: downvote removed once your post was complete).

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding>
      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Something like this should get you close. This was not written in VS so I'm not sure if it's syntactically correct.